# How to express a circumference of half circle with this angle θ?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

So this is my homework:

[image]

$PQ=2$ and $PQ$ is also the radius of the half-circle,
$QR$ is parallel to $PS$,
$P$ is the origin,

How do we express the circumference in terms of $\theta$? I still can't imagine how the size $\theta$ affects the circumference. The question asks to prove that $K = 2 + 6 \cos(\theta) + 2 \sin (\theta)$ where $K$ is the circumference of this half circle.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is $K$?  I don't see it specified anywhere?

Comment: I don’t see a definition for $K$ in the image.

Comment: You will get a better response from mathSE reviewers if you edit your query to show your work.  What have you tried?  Where are you specifically having trouble?

Comment: To link $\theta$ with the circumference, I have to ask you some questions about your math background.  What is the circumference of a circle of radius 2?  Do you measure angles in degrees or radians? Do you understand the coordination between arc length (which is actually a fraction of 1 complete revolution = 1 complete circumference) and the angle which may be construed to be a fraction of 360 degrees or a fraction of $2\pi$ radians?  It is difficult to help without knowing your background here.

Comment: Okay, 4π is the radius. Arc length is θ/2π if it's in radian or θ/360deg if it's in degree. I usually do it in degree tho.

Comment: Just checking: is $P$ not the origin, and should the question say $QR$ is *parallel* to $PS$? Make sure you check your question so that it makes sense to someone reading it for the first time. The more [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)  you include, the better your question.

Comment: Given the answer, most definitely, the question is about
the circumference (aka the perimeter) of $PQRS$,
the point $P$ is the center of the semicircle,
and $|PQ|$ is its radius.

Comment: thank you for all, sorry cuz I'm new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The circumference, or the perimeter of $PQRS$
in terms of the given radius $|PQ|=r=2$ and
the value of angle $\theta$ can be found as follows:

\begin{align}
K&=|PQ|+|QR|+|RS|+|PS|
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
|QR|&=2\,|QT|
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
|QT|&=|PS|=r\cos\theta
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
|RS|&=r\,\sin\theta
\tag{4}\label{4}
,
\end{align}

so, indeed, we have
\begin{align} 
K&=r+2r\cos\theta+r\,\sin\theta+r\cos\theta
=r+3r\cos\theta+r\,\sin\theta
\\
&=2+6\cos\theta+2\,\sin\theta
\tag{5}\label{5}
.
\end{align}

Comment: thank you so much, sir!